# Inverse regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex-negation

I'm trying to remove everything in a string that does not match 'standard' characters. Heres what I have so far:

```
var result = myString.replace(/^(?![A-Za-z0-9]+)/g, '');
```

Which does not work. Can someone point to me what I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
var result = myString.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
```

Comment: No problem. In future, you should probably use a Regex explainer. Compare [your regex](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28%3F%21%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B%29) to [mine](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5B%5Ea-z0-9%5D)